# How do I extract data between square brackets that appear several times in a line using perl?

Tags: regex, perl, data-processing

I have a line that containes multiple instances of square bracketed data.

```
[data 1] junk [data 2] junk,junk [data 3] junk [data 4]
```

Does any one have a goo regex? So I can use

```
print $1,$2,$3,$4;
```

Thanks!

Comment: How you make that regex depends quite a bit on the junk data. Also, if the square brackets can nest, the language is complex enough that it's not parseable with regular expressions. You can do it with the Perl regex extensions, but it's dirty as hell. It's better to use a parser generator instead in that case.

Comment: Time elapsed [846.078000] to [857.562000], on clock [Clock 1], month[December]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $s = "[data 1] junk [data 2] junk,junk [data 3] junk [data 4]";
my ($one, $two, $three, $four) = $s =~ /\[([^\]]*)\]/g;
print $one, $two, $three, $four;
```

Comment: this assumes that nested pairs of square brackets are not allowed.

Comment: I need something where I can use print $1, $2, $3, $4

Comment: @seaworthy, i'm not going to change this to use $1, $2, $3, $4, but i've edited my response to allow for equivalent usage.

Comment: A slight alternative which is a little less noisy would be `/\[(.*?)\]/g`, i.e. use lazy repetition

Answer (score 7):

Use [Text::Balanced](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aBalanced) instead of a regex.

Answer (score 1):

If all your looking for is a quick printout, this should do it ..

`$s =  q( [data 1] junk [data 2] junk,junk [data 3] junk [data 4] );`
`print  join(', ', @{[$s =~ /\[(.*?)\]/g]}), "\n";`